# how do I filter out errant integer data in pentaho data integration

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a fixed position input.txt file like this:

> 4033667    70040118401401
> 4033671    70040/8401901    < not int because of "/"
> 4033669    70040118401301
> 4033673    70060118401101

I'm using a text file input step to pull the data in, and I'd like to load the data into a database as int's and have errant data go to a log file.

I've tried to using the filter step and the data validator step, but I can't seem to get either to work.  I've even tried using the text input field to bring it in as a string and then converting it to an int w/ the Select/Rename values Step, and changing the data-type in meta-data section.

a typical error I keep running into is "String : couldn't convert String to Integer"

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using...
Text file input > Filter Rows (regex \d+) > select values (to cast string to int) > table output

...and the error log comes off of the false result of the regex filter.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you problem.
Let do it simple.
[image]